# before_validation to prevent a duplicate category name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a categories model. I want to ensure that a user doesn't add a duplicate category name to his/her list of categories.

Here's my categories model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  before_validation :validate

  private
    def validate
      errors.add(:name, "is already taken") if Category.where("name = '?' AND user_id = ?", self.name, self.user_id).any?
    end
end
```

Here is my RSpec test:

```
it "is invalid with duplicate name for same user" do
  existing_category = Category.first
  new_category = Category.new(:name => existing_category.name, :user_id => existing_category.user_id)
  expect(new_category).to have(1).errors_on(:name)
end
```

Should I use before_save or before_validate? Also, I'm unsure how to write this. I guess if a duplicate is detected, I want to add an error for :name. Above is my attempt but doesn't seem to make it pass, is there anything obviously wrong? Also, is this good practise for adding custom validation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a much simpler way to achieve your goal - you can use `scope` option of [`validates_uniqueness_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of) validator:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :user_id
```

Your spec fails because it has an error. It expect `new_category` has error, but it doesn't run validations on this object. To do that, you just need to add:

```
new_category.valid?
```

before `expect#...` line.

Comment: Don't get why this was downvoted.  If only because Marek didn't notice the user part but now it's updated it's exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: Hi. I've added your suggestion to the model, thanks. When I run the describe block in rails console it seems to do the job. Great! - I guess I've an error in my test but I can't figure out where/ why. Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: No that didn't work either. I don't have `[object].valid?` in my other "it" blocks either but they pass, even when I use expect(...)... Is there anyway I can debug this instance in the spec? I tried debugging in console but it seems everything is fine there.

Comment: @user3265472 you can try `pry`. Add gem 'pry' to your Gemfile, run `bundle` and in your spec add line `binding.pry` where you'd like to stop spec execution and go to ruby console.

Comment: Thanks. Pry helped me debug it, my test db was empty so there was no Category.first. I've used a before hook to load in a single row. I ran `rake db:test:clone` prior though as I thought this would make the db the same as dev, or does it only clone the structure?

Comment: @user3265472 yes, it clones only the structure.

Comment: @user3265472 do you have any other questions?

Comment: No. Using pry, found the problem to be an empty database. Thanks a lot for your suggestion, I'm sure I'll use pry often from now when running tests.

Comment: @user3265472 that's good. 
Please accept my answer if you found it helpful.